# Finding the percent volume of each gas in the gas mixture

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, gas-laws

A gas mixture of $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{N2}$ weighs $\pu{2.00 g}$ and have a volume of $\pu{10.0 L}$ at $\pu{700 mmHg}$ and $\pu{63.0 °C}$. Calculate the vol.% and the partial pressures of the two gases in the mixture.

I have only found the total number of moles using the formula:$PV=nRT$.

But I cant get any further! Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you to start with what is being asked, not a general formula that seems to fit the scope of question, and then unfold the solution in terms of symbolic algebra. Can you write the formulas for the volume fractions $\varphi_1,$ $\varphi_2$ and partial pressures $p_1$ and $p_2$ (indices 1 and 2 refer to hydrogen and nitrogen, respectively) and try to deduce where the missing variables can be found?

Comment: When they say volume percent, what they really mean is mole fraction times 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call $x$ = number of mole $\ce{H2}$, and $y$ = number of moles $\ce{N2}$.
The mass of the gas mixture is : $$x·2 + y·28 = 2 g $$ The total number of moles is $$n = x+y = \frac{pV}{RT} = \frac{700}{760}101325 Pa·\frac{0.01 m^3}{8.314 J K^{-1}mol^{-1}·336 K}= 0.3341 mol$$Here you get two equations with two unknowns. This could be solved by choosing : $x = 0.3341 - y$. The first equation yields : $$2 = 2x + 28 y = 0.6682 - 2y + 28 y = 0.6682 + 26 y$$ $$y = \frac{2 - 0.6682}{26} = 0.0512 mol$$ $$x = 0.3341 mol - y = 0.3341mol - 0.0512mol = 0.2829 mol$$ $$x/n = \frac{0.2829mol}{0.3341mol} = 0.8467 $$ So the molar fraction of $\ce{H2}$ in the mixture is $84.67$% $\ce{H2}$. If you want the volume percent of $\ce{H2}$, you must calculate the volume of $\ce{H2}$ alone, which is $$V(\ce{H2}) = xRT/P = 0.2829 RT/P$$ As the total volume is $V = nRT/P= 0.3341RT/P$, the volume percent of $\ce{H2}$ is $\frac{0.2829mol}{0.3341mol} =  84.67$%. And by the same reasoning, the partial pressure of $\ce{H2}$ is $84.67$% of $700 mm$ Hg, which is $592.7 mm$ Hg.

Comment: Please do not forget to utilize `\pu` macro available on Chemistry.SE for units. Unit symbols *must be upright*, otherwise they can be interpreted as *variables*, and they also have to be separated with a space from the numerical values they attached to. $1mm$ Hg is wrong, but $\pu{1 mmHg}$ is correct. See the difference? The proper formatting is achieved with `$\pu{1 mmHg}$`. For more info, check out [Units formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know/3045#3045) on Meta.

Comment: It's also a good practice to avoid the buzzword "*number of moles*". Despite a widespread usage, it's an illiterate term. See [Meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4436/buzzwords-season-9-number-of-moles-reboot) on this issue. It's advisable to use a proper term *amount of substance* (e.g. "*amount of nitrogen*" in place of "*number of moles N2*"), especially when you are supposedly teaching younger students so that the improper terminology doesn't stick with them.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer given in elsewhere, I just want to point out one easy way to calculation. In this way you can avoid too many unit conversions to achieve your answer. Be aware that the Gas constant $R$ can be given in few different values [based on its units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant#:%7E:text=The%20gas%20constant%20(also%20known,rather%20than%20energy%20per%20temperature)).

Accordingly, you can use $R = \pu{62.36 L Torr K-1 mol-1}$ since given data $(p = \pu{700 mmHg} = \pu{700 Torr}$; and $V = \pu{10.0 L})$ are consistent with that value. Thus, from gas law for ideal gases, $pV = nRT$:

$$n = \frac{pV}{RT} =  \frac{\pu{700 Torr} \times \pu{10.0 L}}{\pu{62.36 L Torr K-1 mol-1} \times \pu{336 K}} = \pu{0.334 mol}$$

Since, $n = n_\ce{H2} + n_\ce{N2}$, and $2 \times n_\ce{H2} + 25 \times n_\ce{N2} = \pu{2 g}$, You have following two equations with two unknowns:

$$n_\ce{H2} + n_\ce{N2} = 0.334 \tag{1}$$
$$2n_\ce{H2} + 28n_\ce{N2} = 2 \tag{2}$$

Take $(2) - 2 \times (1)$, and you get:

$$26n_\ce{N2} = 2 - 0.668 = 1.332 \; \Rightarrow \; n_\ce{N2} = \frac{1.332}{26} = \pu{0.0512 mol}$$

Thus, from $(1)$:

$$n_\ce{H2} = 0.334 - n_\ce{N2} = 0.334 - 0.0512 = \pu{0.2828 mol}$$

Once you know $n_\ce{H2}$ and $n_\ce{N2}$, you can find their volumes under given conditions:

$$V_\ce{H2} = \frac{n_\ce{H2}RT}{p} = \frac{\pu{0.2828 mol} \times \pu{62.36 L Torr K-1 mol-1} \times \pu{336 K}}{\pu{700 Torr}} = \pu{8.46 L}$$

$$ \therefore \  \% V_\ce{H2} = \frac{\pu{8.46 L}}{\pu{10.0 L}} \times 100 = 84.6\%$$

Therefore, using simple mathematics, you can get $ \% V_\ce{N2} = 100 - 84.6\% = 15.4\%$.

---